# access phone features via iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

is it possible to use iphone's sdk to call a person through an app and have control over the voice etc?

Regards

Comment: place a call, yes. control it..no.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to call a person using the iPhone sdk. Try this -

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://8004664411"]];
```

But its not possible to control over voice or even call log. Because "phone" is a separate application and Apple does not allow to interact with this app.